# iptables NAT/Forwarding with external ADSL router; PCs on the network can't access the internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, nat

I'm setting up a firewall/gateway (Ubuntu server 8.04.1)

The firewall has three NIC's:
eth0 192.168.0.2
eth1 192.168.1.2
eth2 192.168.2.2

eth1 is connected directly to the ADSL router (which also has NAT on it)
The IP of the ADSL router is 192.168.1.1

PCs on 192.168.0.x need access to the internet via the router
(The gateway is set to 192.168.0.2, for each of them)

Servers on 192.168.2.x receive traffic from the internet

Here's the firewall script as I have it so far **(UPDATED)**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Local - eth0 - 192.168.0.*
# Comms - eth1 - 192.168.1.*
# Servr - eth2 - 192.168.2.*

iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD

iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP


# Loopback

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT


# SSH

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


# DNS

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth1 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth2 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT


# Firewall outgoing (access 80,443,53 from the firewall itself; don't open up for unrelated incoming connections)

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


# NAT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth2 -j ACCEPT

echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


# Allow responses

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


# Load balance

iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m nth --counter 0 --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.81
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m nth --counter 0 --every 3 --packet 1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.82
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m nth --counter 0 --every 3 --packet 2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.83


# ICMP

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

iptables -N icmp_accept
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type ttl-exceeded -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -j icmp_accept


# Anti DoS

#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT


# Logging

iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES-DROP " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Firewall's gateway is set to 192.168.1.1

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.2.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

ip route list
    192.168.2.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.2
    192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2
    192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2
    default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1  metric 100

The firewall

- can ping IPs on the internet
- can't http to IPs on the internet

The PCs
 - can ping the firewall
 - can't http / ping IPs on the internet

Already ran:
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

This was more or less the recommended configuration as I gathered from various sites.
Any suggestions on how I can get the PCs to access sites on the internet through the firewall?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your routing table?

Comment: Are you saying that your ADSL router is on the local LAN and your firewall is at the same level?  Your ADSL router is also providing firewalling or just NAT to the real internet?

Comment: `Ubuntu server 8.04.1` : you really should consider upgrading to a more recent distro. 8.04's support is ending in 3 months.

Comment: There is something wrong in your setup's description: `eth1 is connected directly to the ADSL router [...] The IP of the ADSL router is 192.168.0.1` but eth1 is configured as 192.168.1.2/24, should the ADSL router IP be 192.168.1.1?

Comment: @syneticon-dj thanks; well spotted!

Comment: @Matt That's correct; the router is rather _limited_ (also only has one lan connection) and I want something between it and the rest of the network for routing and another layer of protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp ! --syn -j ACCEPT
```

with

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also I don't see any rules for your gateways traffic, except icmp (INPUT and OUTPUT).

Comment: I wouldn't. There really is no reason to employ a different state machine for TCP which implementations are state machines already. Filtering for state-related flags is sufficient.

Comment: Connection tracking is a nice feature of iptables. Why not to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing basic FORWARD table rules - your packets are forwarded on their way to the internet, but the responses are DROPped as you have not defined any rules to accept them and set the default FORWARD policy to DROP. I would add

```
# ACCEPT reverse path packets for outbound TCP connections
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp ! --syn -j ACCEPT
# ACCEPT reverse path packets for outbound UDP "connections"
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# create and fill icmp_accept chain with rules for desired ICMP messages
iptables -N icmp_accept
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type ttl-exceeded -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
iptables -A icmp_accept -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT

# allow necessary ICMP
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -j icmp_accept
```

YMMV depending on what kind of security and what level of logging you would need, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Right about the forward rules, but still missing something (PCs still can't ping or http out; the firewall also can't http out). I've added Drop logging; some things do show up, but nothing while I ping/http. I've also tried setting policy to ACCEPT by default and made sure there aren't any DROPs in the script. Still no luck.

Comment: @eugene could you update the ruleset in your question to reflect the current situation?

Comment: thanks for your interest! I've updated the post to reflect the firewall script, in its present state